# WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted

Tags: mongodb

I am completely new in developing and just have installed mongoDB with the help of ducumentation provided by mongodb.com
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

After entering mongod in the console.it shows waiting for connections on port 27017...which is ok

but when I open a new tab and enter the command :- mongo
I show various Warning

```
WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2020-07-01T15:17:26.709+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is a security warning we put in the mongo shell to prevent you accidentally creating a MongoDB cluster with no access controls and then watching in dismay as the Internet deletes all your data or worse.

Comment: On the other hand it permits only local connections, so threats from the internet are not relevant here. But in general the warning is valid.